# Why in JavaScript expression 255 << 24 is a negative number?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

When I run this code here:

```
console.log(255<<24==0xff000000)
```

I get a false instead of true. Why is that?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/337572/613130

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because JavaScript numbers are IEEE-754 double-precision floating point, not 32-bit integers. So `0xff000000` is a large positive number (decimal 4,278,190,080), not a negative number as it would be if that were a signed 32-bit integer.

When you do `<<`, the number being shifted (255 in your case) is temporarily [converted to a signed 32-bit integer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.1) for the purposes of doing the bit shift:

```
00000000000000000000000011111111
^\                             /
| \----- significant bits ----/
+------- sign bit
```

When we shift that 24 places left, a 1 bit ends up in the sign bit:

```
11111111000000000000000000000000
^\                             /
| \----- significant bits ----/
+------- sign bit
```

...and so the result ends up being negative, and gets turned back into a negative IEEE-754 number (-16,777,216 decimal). -16,777,216 is not equal to 4,278,190,080.

(The range of IEEE-754 double-precision floats is larger than the range of 32-bit signed integers. I'm not quite sure why I feel that's relevant, but I do, so I guess I'll leave it in the answer...)

Comment: Note that these conversions are to be thought of as abstract operations to explain semantics - not something that actually happens

Comment: @Esailija: An implementation can take short-cuts, so long as the result matches the description. In this case, I'm not seeing a better shortcut than actually doing what the spec describes.

Comment: You simply just perform the bitwise operation on the integer you already have - no conversions at all.

Comment: @Esailija: If an engine starts out with integers rather than floating-point numbers, *again*, that's an optimization, and it's allowed provided the results are as though it had started out with floats.

Answer (score 2):

Look at it this way. This should look intuitive to you:

```
255<<24 == 0xff000000<<0          // Returns true
```

Bitwise operators work on integral numbers not on number types. Consider it as an equivalent to type casting as in other languages, where you happen to be putting a larger size number into smaller one & you lose stuff...

Javascript sacrifices precision to allow larger figures due to the  floating point format, adopted.

So Javascript would lose the precision for 0xff000000, the same way as it did for 255.

Answer (score 1):

`0xff000000` doesn't specify bits of a 32-bit integer but a real number in hexadecimal base. For instance `0xff000000000000000000000` is `4.932417344027687e+27`

All bitwise operations except `>>>` give the operand int32 semantics, with `>>>` giving uint32 semantics.

You may therefore use `| 0` as a kind of `int` declaration or `(int)` cast:

```
255 << 24 == (0xff000000 | 0)
true
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise operations in javascript convert a number to a *signed* 32-bit integer, as described by T.J., so you only have 31 bits for safely comparing to a hex literal.  If you want to preserve the unsigned number you really want (as opposed to casting your hex literal to the same negative number), do this:

```
255 * (1 << 24) == 0xff000000
```