# 64bit bitwise AND not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bitwise-operators

I am trying to do bitwise AND operation on long numbers in Javascript.

I have tried both the solution given at ([How to do bitwise AND in javascript on variables that are longer than 32 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637702/how-to-do-bitwise-and-in-javascript-on-variables-that-are-longer-than-32-bit)) but none of it was accurate with the numbers I am working with. I have created a plunker for the same to demonstrate the issue.

`Plunker`http://plnkr.co/edit/awFGFKxpkmwIPpnJ06lu?p=preview

Any suggestion/help will be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a library which is giving correct result of Long numbers. It's Long.js.

Found it from [Performing bitwise operations on large values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430636/performing-bitwise-operations-on-large-values?lq=1)

I have browserify the library to use it in angular directly.
The plunker is also updated with browerify JS and correct ans in Result2 textbox.

`Plunker`http://plnkr.co/edit/awFGFKxpkmwIPpnJ06lu?p=preview

-Jimit

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript numbers are 64-bit floating point values. The format is such that integers requiring more than 53 bits cannot be represented exactly. There's no way around that problem without the assistance of a library that provides a complete alternative number representation. Once a value expressed as a numeric constant in source code is turned into a number when the program runs, it's already too late.

Your sample code involves a number that requires 60 bits. That means the low 7 bits (or so; it's a little more complicated than that) are gone, so the `AND` operation with `8` turns up zero.

Comment: Maybe I should have written, "a bit more complicated"

Comment: it's 9 bit more complicated :-)