# Efficient and safe Javascript bitwise/shift operations

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, bit-manipulation, overflow

I've encountered the problem in this question:
[JavaScript: Bitwise shift of long long number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337355/javascript-bitwise-shift-of-long-long-number)

and converted all my relevant places in code from shifts to Math.pow(2,x) operations. Now I'm encountered a serious performance problem.

Is there a "gold way" to go? I mean a safe shift operations (until 50 bits is enough for my purpose) which are also performing well?

Comment: Using only the right 50 bits would probably be an acceptable solution, no ? Using a little more numbers shouldn't be costly. In any case Math.pow looks like a very very bad one

Comment: But how do I use those 50 bits? I thought about using two variables, but I wonder if there is a better solution or a library which does it for me

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/long

This library is exactly what I need - it implements a 64 bit long.
(It does not support "Big integer" - an infinite bit length integer, but if you need an efficient code for long integer it seems to be OK).