# FD_SET and FD_ISSET macros written in javascript

Tags: javascript, c, linux, macros, jsctypes

My friend and I worked on this a while ago. It is meant for use with js-ctypes. In Linux there are these macros for dealing with adding a list of file descriptors (uint32's) to byte array: `FD_SET` and `FD_IS_SET`. The docs are here - http://linux.die.net/man/2/select

I was wondering if anyone would be able to check if I did this right or does anyone know of anyone that has done in this in javascript? I need to complete 32bit/64bit support for big and little endian but if it's already out there I would love to see it as when we worked on this we had so many uncertainties.

Here is the code, the `fd_set_get_idx` was the helper function this is all based on.

```
var MACROS = {
        fd_set_set: function(fdset, fd) {
            let { elem8, bitpos8 } = MACROS.fd_set_get_idx(fd);
            console.info('elem8:', elem8.toString());
            console.info('bitpos8:', bitpos8.toString());
            fdset[elem8] = 1 << bitpos8;
        },
        fd_set_isset: function(fdset, fd) {
            let { elem8, bitpos8 } = MACROS.fd_set_get_idx(fd);
            console.info('elem8:', elem8.toString());
            console.info('bitpos8:', bitpos8.toString());
            return !!(fdset[elem8] & (1 << bitpos8));
        },
  fd_set_get_idx: function(fd) {
            if (osname == 'darwin' /*is_mac*/) {
                // We have an array of int32. This should hopefully work on Darwin
                // 32 and 64 bit.
                let elem32 = Math.floor(fd / 32);
                let bitpos32 = fd % 32;
                let elem8 = elem32 * 8;
                let bitpos8 = bitpos32;
                if (bitpos8 >= 8) {     // 8
                    bitpos8 -= 8;
                    elem8++;
                }
                if (bitpos8 >= 8) {     // 16
                    bitpos8 -= 8;
                    elem8++;
                }
                if (bitpos8 >= 8) {     // 24
                    bitpos8 -= 8;
                    elem8++;
                }

                return {'elem8': elem8, 'bitpos8': bitpos8};
            } else { // else if (osname == 'linux' /*is_linux*/) { // removed the else if so this supports bsd and solaris now
                // :todo: add 32bit support
                // Unfortunately, we actually have an array of long ints, which is
                // a) platform dependent and b) not handled by typed arrays. We manually
                // figure out which byte we should be in. We assume a 64-bit platform
                // that is little endian (aka x86_64 linux).
                let elem64 = Math.floor(fd / 64);
                let bitpos64 = fd % 64;
                let elem8 = elem64 * 8;
                let bitpos8 = bitpos64;
                if (bitpos8 >= 8) {     // 8
                    bitpos8 -= 8;
                    elem8++;
                }
                if (bitpos8 >= 8) {     // 16
                    bitpos8 -= 8;
                    elem8++;
                }
                if (bitpos8 >= 8) {     // 24
                    bitpos8 -= 8;
                    elem8++;
                }
                if (bitpos8 >= 8) {     // 32
                    bitpos8 -= 8;
                    elem8++;
                }
                if (bitpos8 >= 8) {     // 40
                    bitpos8 -= 8;
                    elem8++;
                }
                if (bitpos8 >= 8) {     // 48
                    bitpos8 -= 8;
                    elem8++;
                }
                if (bitpos8 >= 8) {     // 56
                    bitpos8 -= 8;
                    elem8++;
                }

                return {'elem8': elem8, 'bitpos8': bitpos8};
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: What's wrong with good old `>>`, `<<` and `&`, `|`

Comment: Also, could use a `for` loop there...

Comment: I can't understand if you just want to emulate the `FD_XXX` functions or if you have to be compliant with something. JS, specially ES6, has [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) and [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) if you want to use them. Anyway if the semantic of `FD_SET(i, set)` is just `set[i] = i` I don't see any problem in implementing it, in any endianess or size, from scratch. Can you clarify? Also this `fdset[elem8] = 1 << bitpos8` is likely wrong.

Comment: Thanks very much @Margaret and Anti - yep we tried to just emulate `FD_XXX`, no compliance with anything. Honestly this was years ago and I can't remember it if that semantic is correct. I don't think it is, as when I was using this just now, the index `idx` in above code is different. (this is why I added the tags for linux and c to this question. I know it might get closed but I have no one else to ask who has this kind of knowledge. all my skills allow for are using these functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I leave the burden of identify the endianness and the word size to you.
The code below emulates the *FD_XXX* functions and lets you specify the endianness and the size.

```
<!doctype>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var SIZE_32 = 4
            var SIZE_64 = 8

            var LITTLE_ENDIAN = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
            var BIG_ENDIAN = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];

            function fdset(setSize, endianness, size)
            {
                var buffer = new Uint8Array(div(setSize + 7, 8));



                function div(a, b)
                {
                    return Math.floor(a / b);
                }

                function make_index(index)
                {
                    return div(index, 8 * size) * size + endianness[div(index % (8 * size), 8)] % size;
                }

                buffer.set_bit = function(index)
                {
                    buffer[make_index(index)] |= 1 << (index % 8);
                };

                buffer.clear_bit = function(index)
                {
                    buffer[make_index(index)] &= ~(index % 8);
                };

                buffer.get_bit = function(index)
                {
                    return buffer[make_index(index)] & 1 << (index % 8);
                };

                buffer.zero = function()
                {
                    buffer.fill(0);
                }


                return buffer;
            }

            function FD_SET(fd, fdset)
            {
                fdset.set_bit(fd);
            }

            function FD_ISSET(fd, fdset)
            {
                return !!fdset.get_bit(fd);
            }

            function FD_CLR(fd, fdset)
            {
                return fdset.clear_bit(fd);
            }

            function FD_ZERO(fdset)
            {
                return fdset.zero();
            }


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var s = fdset(128, LITTLE_ENDIAN, SIZE_64);

            //s in an Uint8Array

            console.log(s);

            FD_SET(0, s);    //Byte 0 = 1
            FD_SET(9, s);    //Byte 1 = 2
            FD_SET(18, s);   //Byte 2 = 4
            FD_SET(27, s);   //Byte 3 = 8
            FD_SET(36, s);   //Byte 4 = 16
            FD_SET(45, s);   //Byte 5 = 32
            FD_SET(54, s);   //Byte 6 = 64
            FD_SET(63, s);   //Byte 7 = 128

            FD_SET(120, s);  //Byte 15 = 1
            FD_SET(113, s);  //Byte 14 = 2
            FD_SET(106, s);  //Byte 13 = 4
            FD_SET(99, s);   //Byte 12 = 8
            FD_SET(92, s);   //Byte 11 = 16
            FD_SET(85, s);   //Byte 10 = 32
            FD_SET(78, s);   //Byte 9 = 64
            FD_SET(71, s);   //Byte 8 = 128

            console.log(s);

            //64 bits, BE: [128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]
            //64 bits, LE: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
            //32 bits, BE: [8, 4, 2, 1, 128, 64, 32, 16, 16, 32, 64, 128, 1, 2, 4, 8]
            //32 bits, LE: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `fdset` function return an `Uint8Array` that you can pass to a native function or further elaborate.
The `setSize` sets the maximum file descriptor supported.

---

Note that *js ctypes* already has an array type and the usual `[U]intXX_t` types in the native endianness, alas there is not a type that map to 32/64 bits integers based on the platform and there is not a `sizeof` operator<sup>2</sup>, so you still need to perform an external check to detect the word size.

Using *ctypes* would be more natural.
For reference purpose [here](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sys/select.h) is the official implementation of the *FD_XXX* functions.

You could define a [struct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/StructType) with a single field of type [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/ArrayType) of [uint32/64_t](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/ctypes#Predefined_data_types).
Then mimic then behavior of the C source code, being careful to use [UInt64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/UInt64) when needed<sup>1</sup> and avoiding [shifts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337355/javascript-bitwise-shift-of-long-long-number).

---

<sup>1</sup> JS has only double numbers, these numbers have 53 bits of mantissa, 10 bits of exponent and 1 bit of sign. When the bit operators are used the double number is converted into an integer, since it is the mantissa that specify the precision (exponent is just a scale, sign just an inversion), this number can at most carry as much information as a 53 bits number.

<sup>2</sup> That I am aware of, I am not an expert at all in *js ctypes*.

Comment: Wow a sincere thank you for this effort! I remember last when I worked on this I drowned in reading these links - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/5ddc5fe43dd9b0d5a207d0f70d72efc4 - I'll check out your code now! :)

Comment: @Noitidart You are welcome. Double check it, I'm not sure I've really understood your needs!

Comment: I have to admit, I actually had no idea what the code above was doing. I copied it from another js-ctypes project. I phrased it like I did it with a friend because I was worried this would get closed and I couldn't find any help. I am a js coder that can port the C stuff to js if it's 1-to-1. I don't understand endianess, 32bit and 64bit stuff. Would you have like 30min free sometime to use stackoverflow chat about this code? I use it in ctypes so I pass it to actual platform C apis, so the buffer is what I needed. But I get confused from the start of it, including setting the size. :(

Comment: @Noitidart I'm at work now. Edit the question with all the details you think are relevant. I'll update my answer if I can find a solution :)

Comment: Thanks Margaret a lot. My top question is, if I have X number of `fd`'s and the biggest `fd` is Y, how could I determine the size to use. The place I stole this from years ago showed me this is how to use the original - https://github.com/Noitidart/jscFileWatcher/blob/master/DirectoryWatcherPollWorker.js#L406-L414

Comment: @Noitidart You can think as a `FDSET` as a set that can hold all the descriptor from 0 to `setSize`. Just passing *Y* as `setSize` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks very much! The other question I had was in the original he was doing different stuff because his comments said "on linux they are long ints", because I do this in ctypes, the type matters, does this mean there needs to be padding between the bytes? In comments he said he needs to add 32bit support, my thinking is in 64bit it is a 64bit number, and in 32bit its a 32bit, I was wondering how that would differ. In ctypes, a 64bit number is just the string of it as js cant go past 53bits (this bits thing i also dont understand lol)

Comment: @Noitidart I've taken a look at the Linux source for implementing the *FD_XXX*. It effectively use an array of `unsigned long` and not of bytes. I'll write new answer later, as this brings endianness and word size into play. Please unaccept this answer so I can delete it. Thanks :)

Comment: Wow a sincere thank you @Margaret for your awesome awesome help. I posted asking someone for help a year ago but got nothing. I'm a hobbyist but I make some useful stuff people like, I'm using this for a filewatcher submodule in Firefox addons, silly people don't help me out with PRs or explanations though haha. But they say they are egaerly awaiting me to finish so they can use it!!!